# Linkedlist traversal of an array using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, sizeof

I am new to C programming,

```
char a[100];
struct LinkedList {
    size_t size;
    int free;
    struct LinkedList *next; 
};

struct LinkedList *freeList = (void *) a;
```

The above code is used to create a struct type linkedlist in order to traverse `char` array named 'a'. I just want to know what happens from `struct LinkedList *freeList = (void *) a;` in the code and also I want to know the size of the `Linkedlist` structure

Comment: If it isn't completely obvious, this is written for anyone trying to answer this question. The line: `struct LinkedList *freeList = (void *) a;` causes undefined behavior in most cases on modern machines, and dereferencing `freeList` will always cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 Since it isn't obvious perhaps you should answer quoting the standard and explaining why it is undefined behavior.

Comment: I hope you have a damn good reason for programming in this way

Answer (score 0):

Declare a local pointer and assign it to head pointer, then run it trough entire array, and you'll pass trough each element in the array.

```
 int traverse(struct LinkedList* head) {

  struct LinkedList* it = head;
  int size = 0;

  while(it != NULL) {
    size++;
    it = it->next;
  }

  return size;
}
```

Comment: thanx mate i just want to know what happens in my code from struct LinkedList *freeList=(void*)a; code segment

Comment: @SunethPerera Undefined behavior happens.

Answer (score 0):

For your Query :-

***I just want to know what happens from `struct LinkedList *freeList = (void *) a`; in the code***

Nothing will happen. It will work fine, and your structure pointer will point to base address of array.

***I want to know the size of the Linkedlist structure.***

If you try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(struct LinkedList));` it will probably print 24, by the way struct size depend on architecture.

And if you try with struct `LinkedList *freeList1;`
`printf("%d\n", sizeof(freeList));` will probably give you 8 (64bit machine).

Comment: Hello, please be aware that since the size is architecture dependent as you said, you can't ensure it will print `24`. That's why I edited the answer. Also, you can learn about markdown in the help section of the site, that way you can improve the visual quality and readability of your answers. The rest of course, is good taste. Whether you care about how your answer looks and if the users can read it clearly is a matter of taste.

Comment: @inarob, thanks for editing. For size, I already machine in 64 bit machine you will 24.

Answer (score -2):

To find the number of elements in the linkedlist, you can follow the above method. But to find the size of the linkedlist,

```
char a[100];
struct LinkedList {
    size_t size;
    int free;
    struct LinkedList *next;
};

struct LinkedList *freeList = (void *)a;

int main()
{
    struct LinkedList l;
    std::cout << sizeof(l) << endl << sizeof(l.size) << endl << sizeof(l.free) << endl << sizeof(l.next);
    std::cout << endl << "size of freelist : " << sizeof(freeList);
    _getch();
}
```

You cannot have struct LinkedList *freeList = (void *) a; You will get an error saying

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'void *' to 'LinkedList *'
>   note: Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Hope this helps.